# Can't see rendered MathJax

Tags: discussion, support, math-display

I'm trying to see the MathJax equations but all I can see is the `$$` with the text in it.

What's happening ? Do I need to install a plugin? I'm currently using Chrome as browser.

Example:

$$ 
accuracy = \frac{TP+FN}{TP+FP+TN+FN} 
$$

Comment: See this [related post](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/2947/930).

Comment: @chl how this related post woudl help me? I still can't see the formatted equations. I'm wondering if there a plugin to use, or I should be able to see the formatted equation yet?

Comment: Whatever problem you are having is unlikely to be related to this site: it must be specific to some unusual configurations or limitations on your end.  Such problems, whenever reported, seem to have been temporary.

Comment: Try to close the browser and open it again. Did it help? If not, try to clear your browser's cache and reload the page. Did it help?

Comment: Just found out what was! The proxy of network's company (I'm at work) is blocking this feature somehow. Thanks for the attention! @amoeba

Comment: @AlvaroJoao: This is bizarre. So the company proxy is blocking mathjax.org where the JS scripts are located? How did you find out? Can you access mathjax.org in your browser?

Comment: @amoeba I found out when I used the network tool in Chrome's Developer Tools. Blocked this script: 
**http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full**. Afterward, I allowed the `UltraSurf plugin` and worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I think it would be better if this thread is reopened and you posted an answer yourself explaining how to diagnose and circumvent the problem, it might be helpful for future readers.